# XML format date with JSTL

Tags: xml, jstl

my XML look like this

```
<test>
<dateOfTest>2010-05-01T11:12:55</dateOfTest>
</test>
```

I retrive the date using x:parse then i use formatDate to format the date.

```
<fmt:formatDate var="fmt_date" value="${date}"pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
    <label>Date  :</label><label> ${fmt_date} </label>
```

But i have this error when i excute.

```
javax.el.ELException: Cannot convert 2014-02-01T12:00:00 of type class java.lang.String to class java.util.Date
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse the retrived String first then use fmt:formatDate

```
<fmt:parseDate value="${date}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss" var="myDate"/>
<fmt:formatDate var="fmt_date" value="${myDate}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" />
<label>Date  :</label><label> ${fmt_date} </label>
```